# Splunk - how to sum up lots of different columns?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I've got a splunk query that has a bunch of columns, that have the value 1 or 0, for each record in the result set.

e.g.

| hasWidth | hasHeight | isEnabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |

I'd like to run a splunk query that sums up those columns in a table, e.g.

| hasWidthCount | hasHeightCount | isEnabledCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using stats and sum for each field

```
| stats sum(hasWidth) as hasWidthCount, sum(numExpiringToday) as numExpiringCount, sum(isEnabled) as isEnabledCount
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sum up all fields with a single `stats` clause.  This is handy if the field names are not known in advance or if the number of fields changes.

```
| stats sum(*) as *
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works, but it selects all fields that are available.
Is there a way to filter it down to only work on certain fields?
I tried using a `fields` command before piping to stats, but that didn't work

Comment: A `fields` command should have worked.  Make sure the command passes all fields used by `stats`.